# MVVM: Bind property in ViewModel to property in a different VM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

Using MVVMLight toolkit in a WPF app.
I have a ViewModel class that encapsulates the application's settings, and a corresponding View to allow the user to change them.  The settings are stored in the registry.

I'm adding some status indicators to the main View to reflect whether some settings are toggled on or off.  It makes sense to bind the visibility of these to properties in the MainViewModel.
Is it possible to bind properties in the MainViewModel to properties in the SettingsViewModel, or should I use messages to tell the MainViewModel that something has changed in the SettingsViewModel?
Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do it by exposing the SettingsViewModel as a property on your MainViewModel like this:

```
Public SettingsViewModel Settings
{
    get
    {
       return settingsViewModel;
    }
}
```

Then in your MainView.xaml your binding can do this:

```
"{Binding Path=Settings.ASettingOnTheSettingsVM}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I have done.  Since the SettingsView binds to the SettingsViewModel, I had to add some xxxTemp properties for the SettingsView to bind to.  When the user clicks 'Save' on the SettingsView, the persisted properties -- the ones MainView controls are bound to -- get updated.

Comment: That's a useful solution, but doesn't this break the MVVM-pattern? Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

If your `SettingsViewModel` is launched from the `MainViewModel` and you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface then you can just listen to the `SettingsViewModel.PropertyChanged` event:

In `MainViewModel`:

```
SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
settingsViewModel.PropertyChanged = SettingsViewModel_PropertyChanged;

...

private void SettingsViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Monitor property changes here
}
```